# How do I add thumbnails to the swiper slider correctly if I use the virtual function for the main slider?

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

I accept the list of files from django into the virtual slides function in swiper slider, it works well, but there is a need to output a slider with thumbnails. If you display thumbnails with the built-in swiper function, the thumbnails do not correspond to the display of the main slider. Is there a good solution by basic means to make the thumbnails work?

```
var js_file_list = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('js_file_list').textContent);
var slides = [];
var slidesThumbs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < js_file_list.length; i++) {
    let file = js_file_list[i];
    let filename = file.toLowerCase();
    if (filename.endsWith('.mp4')) {
        slides.push('<div class="file-slider_file"><video src="' + file + '" controls loop></video></div>');
        slidesThumbs.push('<div class="file-slider_file"><video src="' + file + '"></video></div>');
    }
    if (filename.endsWith('.jpg') || filename.endsWith('.jpeg') || filename.endsWith('.png')) {
        slides.push('<div class="file-slider_file"><img src="' + file + '" alt="Image ' + i + '"/></div>');
        slidesThumbs.push('<div class="file-slider_file"><img src="' + file + '" alt="Image ' + i + '"/></div>');
    }
}
new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    grabCursor: true,
    keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
        pageUpDown: true,
    },
    mousewheel: {
        sensitivity: 1,
        eventsTarget: ".file-slider",
    },
    watchOverflow: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    virtual: {
        slides: slides,
    },
    thumbs: {
        swiper: {
            el: '.file-mini-slider',
            virtual: {
                slides: slidesThumbs,
            },
            freeMode: true,
            watchSlidesVisibility: true,
            watchSlidesProgress: true,
        },
    },
});
```

I tried to make a separate slider for thumbnails, and then link it to the main one, but then scrolling of both sliders does not work correctly